# ubuntu 18.04 Login Loop Problem

Tags: login, lightdm

I am facing a login loop problem in Ubuntu 18.04 similar to [another login loop problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687256/another-login-loop-problem)

I have also changed the `.profile` file so that:

```
grep -H PATH ~/.profile 
/home/trilok/.profile:PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

But I also get:

```
grep -H PATH ~/.bash_profile 
~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

...and...

```
grep -H PATH ~/.bashsrc 
~/.bashsrc: No such file or directory
```

The contents of xsession-errors is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/gettext.sh: line 88: gettext command not found  
/usr/bin/gettext.sh: line 88: envsubst command not found  
/usr/bin/gettext.sh: line 88: envsubst command not found  
/usr/lib/lightdm/config-error-dialog.sh: line19: gettext: command not found  
/usr/lib/lightdm/config-error-dialog.sh: line20: fold: command not found  
/usr/lib/lightdm/config-error-dialog.sh: line28: zenity: command not found  
/usr/sbin/lightdm-sesion: line 33: cat: command not found  
/usr/sbin/lightdm-sesion: line 34: truncate: command not found  
/usr/sbin/lightdm-sesion: line 33: cat: command not found  
/usr/sbin/lightdm-sesion: line 34: truncate: command not found  
/usr/sbin/lightdm-sesion: line 106: ls: command not found  
/usr/sbin/lightdm-sesion: line 117: exec: command not found
```

Comment: Did you also modify the `/etc/environment` file? or any files related to PAM?

Comment: The contents of /etc/environment was initially blank . and the contents of /etc/environment.bak is export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" . I added the same path to /etc/environment also .I didnt modify files related to PAM

Comment: There should be no `export` keyword in `/etc/environment` - it's a configuration file not a shell script

Comment: yes I changed it, but still the login loop problem exists

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following commands from the terminal and it worked.

echo "export PATH="/bin:$PATH"" >> ~/.profile

echo "export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"" >> ~/.profile

Though the error in ./xsession_errors still exits ,the login loop problem is solved.