# X no longer starts on successful login on Ubuntu 18.04? Successful login returns back to login screen (Login Loop)

Tags: 18.04, login, xorg, display

Today I was in a Zoom call, my mic stopped working so I rebooted my computer (sudo shutdown -r after I previously had not rebooted my computer for 7 days), and then after that looks like X no longer starts upon successful login anymore? My desktop interface no longer displays my desktop icons or anything upon successful login, it just loops right back to the LightDM login prompt after successfully logging in.

I have tried uninstalling my NVIDIA driver (460) and just using Nouveau, I have tried using gdm3 instead of lightdm, I have tried using Ubuntu (Gnome) instead of Xfce 4.12 DE, nothing seems to work. In order to get into my graphical desktop, I need to log in via TTY (crtl+alt+f1 IIRC) and then I must manually type `startx` as my regular user `ken` and then I can now see my desktop GUI with all my desktop icons, etc. I never had to do this before, though? My computer had an uptime of around 7 days before rebooting it today. Creating a new user account also did not help.

I booted at February 1, 2021 successfully, here is the uprecords proof:
`37     6 days, 19:30:11 | Linux 4.15.0-135-generic  Mon Feb  1 19:47:34 2021`

Here is a list of automatic upgrades my automatic upgrade script has done since February 1 2021:
https://pastie.io/zlzpvu.sql

Also, I have a file called core in my home, `sudo file core` reports the following:
`core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :1 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -noliste', real uid: 0, effective uid: 0, real gid: 0, effective gid: 0, execfn: '/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg', platform: 'x86_64'`

Running `gdb /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg $HOME/core` then `bt` returns this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIj1T.png

`cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log` returns this: https://pastie.io/nkdgib.hs

`cat /var/log/Xorg.1.log` returns this: https://pastie.io/uyycjy.dns

`cat /var/log/Xorg.2.log` returns this: https://pastie.io/rvdovy.dns

`cat $HOME/.xsession-errors` returns this: https://pastie.io/zlfaow.md

`dmesg` returns this: https://pastie.io/bhiuhw.dns

`journalctl | tail -50000` returns this: https://pastebin.com/kNTF0uXW

Computer specs:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x86_64 
Host: All Series 
Kernel: 4.15.0-135-generic 
Uptime: 16 mins 
Packages: 4472 
Shell: zsh 5.4.2 
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1200 
WM: Xfwm4 
WM Theme: Default 
Theme: Greybird [GTK3] 
Icons: Elementary-xfce-darker [GTK3] 
Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
Terminal Font: Hack 12 
CPU: Intel i7-5960X (16) @ 4.300GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 
Memory: 7215MiB / 32081MiB
```

I would appreciate any suggestions anyone has to look into.

Comment: From my research thus far, I think I may have messed up my $PATH. 

I noticed in my $HOME/.xsession-errors, I get the same exact errors as another person who has a login loop: https://askubuntu.com/questions/687256/another-login-loop-problem

This looks promising.

Comment: That was it, adding the solution as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

Over the weekend, I had installed Java 17 manually, and I created /etc/profile.d/jdk17.sh that contained this (I created it via CLI instead of via a text editor):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-17
export PATH=\$PATH:\$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

However, my existing /etc/profile.d/jdk14.sh looked like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-14
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

It turns out, the backslashes broke the path - I was essentially setting the $PATH to nothing.

In my `$HOME/.xsession-errors` file, I did notice these errors:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: cat: command not found

/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 34: truncate: command not found

/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: cat: command not found

/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 34: truncate: command not found

/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 106: ls: command not found

/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 117: exec: startxfce4: not found

Xsession: X session started for ken at Mon Feb  8 18:15:50 EST 2021
```

The errors (combined with other Ask Ubuntu questions) pretty much gave it away right away what was happening - the PATH was having issues.

The issue is now solved and I am as happy as a clam.

Hopefully this helps someone else who runs into this.