# Ubuntu login loop lightdm-session errors

Tags: bash, login, lightdm

I have been trying to solve this problem for over a month now, so of course I have tried all the 3 common solutions which are all over the internet. I think I am getting close and my problem resembles this particular problem: [another login loop problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687256/another-login-loop-problem)

This is my `.xsession-errors` file:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 24: mktemp: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: : No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: cat: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 34: truncate: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: : No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: cat: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 34: truncate: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 106: ls: command not found
```

Following is the output of `grep -H PATH ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login` and `echo $PATH` and `type gnome-session`:

[image]

notice: no such file or directory for bash_profile and bash_login.

I think the problem has got something to do with my path variable? I am just not sure.

Also, I just started seeing this new error after a recent reboot:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 117: exec: gnome-session: not found
```

Comment: Ubuntu does not have ``bash_profile` or ``bash_login` - that's perfectly normal. Please don't post pictures of your terminal - just paste the text into your question and format it as code.  I think your path is missing `/bin`. Where did you set your path (obviously not in `.profile`)?

Comment: I'm sorry for posting a picture of the terminal, I tried copying the text but could not since it's not the ordinary terminal.
Anyway, I don't think I set the path in .profile. I have been stuck on this login loop even after re-installing ubuntu (pretty weird huh?).

Comment: Also, I just started seeing this new error after a recent reboot:
_/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 117: exec: gnome-session: not found_

Comment: oh sorry, I see your problem with the VT! You (or someone else using your machine) evidently set the path somewhere! Is the assignment in `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profile` for example?

Comment: I DID IT!!!! Please don't mind my excitement I'm just so so happy right now. I had edited .pam_environment to include Android Studio's path which I just deleted after following another post which had the same problem. I can login finally! Thanks for your help @Zanna

Comment: You're welcome, any time :) haha I'm very familiar with that excitement myself, so feel free to enjoy it loudly :D By the way, what was the other post? We can mark your question as a duplicate of that one to help others in the future

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/463213/exec-gnome-session-not-found-when-logging-in-using-lightdm

This helped me realize that .pam_environment might be causing this. Haha thanks I just called my friend and celebrated for a good 10 minutes! :D